# Updating MongoDB Date in String to Date Format

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime

I am re-asking this question as there seemed to be some misunderstanding.  I need to convert a string in my mongo to a date format using Python.  I have the following code:

```
newest_date = datetime.strptime(r["date"], "%Y-%m-%d").isoformat()
```

Which successfully created the following date object (new_date):

```
2017-01-03T00:00:00
```

When I try:

```
db.address.update_one({"address": "1234", {"$set": {"date" : new_date}})
```

I get the item updated in the document but it's still a string, not a date.  I can successfully do it in the shell using:

```
db.address.find({ "date" : { $type : 2 } } ).forEach(function(element){  element.date = ISODate(element.date); db.address.save(element);})
```

How can I update the actual type to be a date because when I do it from the console I get the output:

```
"date": {"$date": "2017-06-28T00:00:00.000Z"
```

},

Comment: Yup. Just supply the `datetime` and let the driver do the rest. You're the one who converted it to a string. So just don't do that and instead: `new_date = datetime.strptime(r["date"], "%Y-%m-%d")` It's the `.isoformat()` that makes it a string. So don't add that part.

Comment: My god, I've been a total idiot.  Thank you so much.. Works perfectly now. Do you want to reply as an answer and I will put it as right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help someone not make the stupid mistake I made.  Make sure you don't append .isoformat() to a datetime object like a clown...

```
newest_date = datetime.strptime(r["date"], "%Y-%m-%d")
```